# How can I build a boat?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How do you you build a boat in Minecraft that moves?

I am having trouble building a moving boat in Minecraft on my iPod.

Comment: Am i the only one wondering about the "I have tried nothing" part?

Comment: I liked the original question title better.

Comment: I have tried nothing, and I expected an outcome...WHAT AM I DOING WRONG?!?!

Comment: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Ilq8SzToP6I/U1Em0tvn4ZI/AAAAAAAAZIQ/gyJ4Elwc8dQ/s1600/out+of+ideas.png

Answer (score 3):

**You can't**. As of Minecraft Pocket Edition version Alpha 0.8.1, it is not possible to craft a boat.